# Count and Percentage of records in range of values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with columns

```
TicketID - ID of the ticket
AssignedTo - UserID of person to whom ticket is assigned
CreatedTime - Time when Ticket is received
HandleTime - Time when Ticket is picked up for handling
FinishTime - Time when Ticket is finished handling
```

I need to retrieve the following data grouped to individual AssignedTo ID:

- AssignedTo
- Picking Rate in the following ranges(both % and count)

  - <1 minutes
  - 1-2 minutes
  - 2-5 minutes
- Closing Rate in the following ranges(both % and count)

  - same ranges as above
- Total Tickets

I have come up with a initial query as

```
SELECT 
   User,
   sum(case when PickupTime <=1 then 1 else 0 end) as range1,
   sum(case when PickupTime <=2 then 1 else 0 end) as range2,
   ...
FROM
   (SELECT 
      ((HandleTime - CreatedTime)/60000) as PickupTime, 
      ((FinishTime - CreatedTime)/60000) as CompletedTime,
      AssignedTo as User 
    FROM 
      TicketTable
    )T
GROUP BY 
    User
```

Here I am able to get only the Pickup range counts.I still need Pickup range percentages and also Closing range counts and percentages.How do I get them?

EDIT:

Let us consider a sample dataset and only two ranges <=1 and >1 and also consider time as minutes directly here whereas in original table its stored as timestamp.

```
TicketID | AssignedTo | CreatedTime | HandleTime | FinishTime
   1          001          2              3           3
   2          001          4              6           8
   3          002          1              2           3
```

In the above table User 001 is assigned a total of 2 tickets and User 002 is assigned a total of 1 ticket.
The PickupTime and CompletedTime for the tickets are

```
TicketID | PickupTime | CompletedTime
    1          1            1
    2          2            4
    3          1            2
```

So for User-001 out of the two tickets assigned to him, he has picked 1 ticket within 1 minute range and 1 greater than 1 minute range.So percentage of tickets within 1 minute range is 50% and over 1 minute range is 50% for him.Same applies with regards to CompletedTime and also to the User-002 too.
So the final result what i want is.

```
AssignedTo | Pickup_range1_count | Pickup_range2_count | Pickup_range1_percentage | 
001           1                       1                     0.5 
002           1                       0                     1        
Pickup_range2_percentage | Complete_range1_count | Complete_range2_count |
         0.5                       1                  1
         0                         0                  1
Complete_range1_percentage | Complete_range2_percentage 
          0.5                       0.5
          0                         1
```

Comment: It would help if you provided desired results.  What do you mean by "Pickup range percentages" and "Closing range counts and percentages"?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added more details.See if you can understand them!

Comment: @Strawberry I have added more details.See if you can understand them!

Comment: Don't worry- If they don't conform to the requirement, then I won't even bother looking at them

Comment: @Strawberry I am sorry if I didn't conform to the requirement. I am new to Posting questions and in fact this is only my second time posting questions.

Answer (score 1):

According to your example you already almost got it. All you need is the ratio of the individual sums and the total sum (or the count would have done it to). Something like

```
SELECT AssignedTo,
       sum(1) AllCount,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN HandleTime - CreatedTime <= 1
               THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) Range1PickupCount,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN HandleTime - CreatedTime > 1
               THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) Range2PickupCount,
       ...
       sum(CASE
             WHEN HandleTime - CreatedTime <= 1
               THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) / sum(1) * 100 Range1PickupPercentage,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN HandleTime - CreatedTime > 1
               THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) / sum(1) * 100 Range2PickupPercentage,
       ...
       FROM Tickets
       GROUP BY AssignedTo;
```

should be a valid demonstration and something you can continue upon.

(Disclaimer: Not tested at all, as no DDL and DML was provided.)